# How do I solve this Listview and checkbox combination?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-checkbox

I am getting **null pointer exception** -error since I the viewholder don't find any Checkbox.
Anyone know how I fix this?

This is the row that get's an error:
           viewHolder.getCheckBox().setChecked( Exercise.isChecked() );
(Marked with arrows further down)

**XML EditWorkout.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mainListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:gravity="bottom">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_EditWorkout_Save"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_Workout_Cancel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cancel"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**XML Simplerow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <TextView android:id="@+id/rowTextView" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:padding="10dp" 
            android:textSize="16sp" /> 
  <CheckBox android:id="@+id/CheckBox01" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:padding="10dp" 
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
            android:layout_marginRight="6sp" 
            android:focusable="false" /> 
  </RelativeLayout>
```

**Java EditWorkout:**

```
    public class EditWorkout extends SherlockActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener
    {

          private ListView mainListView;
          private ArrayAdapter<Exercise> listAdapter;
          private String workoutName;
          ArrayList<Exercise> exerciseList = new ArrayList<Exercise>();


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            workoutName = intent.getStringExtra(ListWorkoutActivity.WORKOUT_NAME);

            setContentView(R.layout.editworkout);
            // Find the ListView resource.   
            mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );  


            // When item is tapped, toggle checked properties of CheckBox and Exercise.  
            mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {


              @Override  
              public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View item,   int position, long id) 
              {  
                Exercise Exercise = listAdapter.getItem( position );
                Exercise.toogleChecked();
                ExerciseViewHolder viewHolder = (ExerciseViewHolder) item.getTag();
               -----> viewHolder.getCheckBox().setChecked( Exercise.isChecked() <------ );
              }//End of onItemClick
            });//End of Listener

 // Since we don't have a database we manually put in exercises
        //Could use a Arraylist directly but we use a String since we will load
        //String-Arrays from the database we use a String-array here

        if(exerciseList.isEmpty())
        {

            exerciseList.add(new Exercise("pushup"));
            exerciseList.add(new Exercise("sit-up"));
            exerciseList.add(new Exercise("sit-up"));
            exerciseList.add(new Exercise("sit-up"));
            exerciseList.add(new Exercise("sit-up"));
        }



        // Set our custom Arrayadapter as the ListView's adapter.
        listAdapter = new ExerciseArrayAdapter(this, exerciseList);
        mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
    }
```

**Java Exercise:**

```
public class Exercise 
{  
  private String name = "" ;  
  private boolean checked = false ; 

  /** 
   * */ 
  public Exercise( String name ) {  
    this.name = name ;  
  }  
  public Exercise( String name, boolean checked ) {  
    this.name = name ;  
    this.checked = checked ;  
  }  
  public String getName() {  
    return name;  
  }   
  public boolean isChecked() {  
    return checked;  
  }  
  public void setChecked(boolean checked) {  
    this.checked = checked;  
  }  
  public String toString() {  
    return name ;   
  }  
  public void toogleChecked() {  
    checked = !checked ;  
  }  
}
```

**Java ExerciseViewHolder:**

> public class ExerciseViewHolder
>        {
>           private CheckBox checkBox;
>           private TextView textView;
>
> ```
>     /**
>      * Creates a new holder with the given name and a checkbox
>      * The name is the name of the exercise
>      */
>     public ExerciseViewHolder( TextView textView, CheckBox checkBox )
>     {
>       this.checkBox = checkBox;
>       this.textView = textView;
>     }
>     /**
>      * Gets the checkbox of the holder
>      * @return the holders checkbox.
>      */
>     public CheckBox getCheckBox()
>     {
>       return checkBox;
>     }
>     /**
>      * Gets the name of the holder
>      * @return the holders name
>      */
>     public TextView getTextView()
>     {  
>       return textView;
>     }
>  }
> ```

```
public class ExerciseArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Exercise> {  

  private LayoutInflater inflater;  

  public ExerciseArrayAdapter( Context context, List<Exercise> exerciseList )
  {  
    super( context, R.layout.simplerow, R.id.rowTextView, exerciseList );  
    // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.  
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  }


  /**Since we display other things than a TextView we need to Override a getView-method.
   * This method is the one that got the focus on the screen and is returning the View
   * when the user clicks on a exercise.
   * @param position        The place where the user clicks refereed as an Int.
   * @param convertView     The view, each view will be represented as an simplerow
   *                        with an textfield and a checkbox.
   * @return View*/
  public View getView(int position, View convertView)
  {  
    // Exercise to display  
    Exercise exercise = (Exercise) this.getItem( position );   
    Log.v("Convertview", String.valueOf(position));

    //What each view contains. 
    CheckBox checkBox;
    TextView textView;

    //If the view doesn't exist, we create a new row view. Initially
    //the screen is filled up, when the screen is full the convertView
    // is not null and will there after go to the else-statement
    if ( convertView == null)
    {
      convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simplerow, null);

      // Find the child views.
      textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.rowTextView );
      checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById( R.id.CheckBox01 );

      // Optimization: Tag the row with it's child views, so we don't have to   
      // call findViewById() later when we reuse the row in our else case.
      convertView.setTag( new ExerciseViewHolder(textView,checkBox) );

      // If CheckBox is toggled, update the Exercise it is tagged with. 
      checkBox.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
      {
        /** When the user click on a exercise, the checkbox
         *  for the exercise is getting unchecked or checked
         *  @param v        The view the user clicks on, this view will
         *                  refeer to a exercise since the view contains
         *                  a exercise.
         *  */
        public void onClick(View v)
        {  
          CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
          Exercise exercise = (Exercise) cb.getTag();
          exercise.setChecked( cb.isChecked() );
        }
      });
    }
    //Is used when the user are scrolling down or up to list existing views but now the
    //the elements  in the highest view with another element if the user scroll up or
    //the lowest view if the user scroll down.
    else
    {
      // Because we use a ViewHolder, we avoid having to call findViewById().  
      ExerciseViewHolder viewHolder = (ExerciseViewHolder) convertView.getTag();  
      checkBox = viewHolder.getCheckBox();
      textView = viewHolder.getTextView();
    }

    // Tag the CheckBox with the Exercise it is displaying, so that we can  
    // access the Exercise in onClick() when the CheckBox is clicked.
    checkBox.setTag( exercise );   

    // Display Exercise 
    checkBox.setChecked( exercise.isChecked() );  
    textView.setText( exercise.getName() );        

    return convertView;  
  }  

}
```